# Find an element in a matrix M*M of numbers which have exactly 3 divisors in given time?

Tags: c++, matrix, primes

This was a task given on a coding competition a few months ago, and its still bugging me now. I did solve it, but my code did not give the result in required time for 3 test samples, likely due to the very large numbers they used. The thing is, looking at my code i see no obvious improvements that would reduce the time further.

The input has 3 numbers: the side length of the matrix, row and column of the required number. For a matrix size 3, it would look like:

```
4   9   16
121 49  25
169 289 361
```

A number that has 3 divisors can only be a squared prime number, so my solution was to generate primes until the needed position.

```
#include<iostream>
bool prime(long long a)
{
    //if(a%2==0) 
    //  return false; //no numbers passed will be even
    for(long long i=3;i*i<=a;i+=2)
        if(a%i==0) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int side, row, col, elem, count=1;
    long long num=1; 
    std::cin >> side >> row >> col;
    if(row==1 && col==1)
    {
        std::cout << '4';
        return 0;
    }
    elem=(row-1)*side+col+(row%2==0)*(side-2*col+1);//gets required position in matrix
    while(count<elem)
    {
        num+=2;
        if(prime(num)) 
            count++;
    }
    std::cout << num*num;
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty naive way of generating primes. Especially when you do it over and over again in a loop. What was the exact problem description, notably the input data ranges? Consider Eratosthenes Sieve for faster prime generation.

Comment: I'll look into Eratosthenes Sieve, it looks pretty interesting on the wiki page.

Comment: There are better modern algorithms, but this one is simple, intuitive, quite fast and only requires a small amount of code to implement ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14803684/1553090))

Comment: How would you know the size of the sieve? If I understand this right you need the `elem`th prime number. A evil solution would be to build an `std::array` of all primes < 2^31 as consexpr. That takes about 15s with a sieve on my system, so not that much of a compile time. Then the code would run in `O(1)`, that should fit in the time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than this:

```
while(count<elem)
{
    num+=2;
    if(prime(num)) 
        count++;
}
```

This:

```
vector<long long> primes;
primes.push_back(2);

while (count < elem)
{
    num += 2;
    if (prime(num, primes)) {
       primes.push_back(num);
       count++;
    }
}
```

Where your `prime` function is modified to only test divisibility against previously found prime numbers:

```
bool prime(long long num, const vector<long long>& primes)
{
   for (auto p : primes)
   {
       if (num % p == 0)
       {
          return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

The above should speed things up significantly.  There's also the sieve of eros thing. But the above should be sufficient for most leet coding challenge sites.

Comment: This seems like such an obvious thing to do, how did i not think of it? I guess i need a lot more experience.

Answer (score 0):

A bare-bones implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes, you could try with this:

```
bool is_prime(size_t p, std::vector<bool>& primes) {
  if (!primes[p]) return false;
  for (auto i = p * p; i < primes.size(); i += p) {
    primes[i] = false;
  }
  return true;
}

void init_primes(std::vector<bool>& primes, size_t N) {
  primes = std::vector(N, true);
  primes[0] = false;
  primes[1] = false;
  primes[2] = true;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<bool> p;
  init_primes(p, 1000); // <- insert some large enough number here
  ...
}
```